# Change entire MySQL drive location?

Tags: mysql

We cloned a VM server and on Server A MySQL is located on the F drive, but on Server B it's located on the E drive. I updated the ini file and the Windows path variables, but it's still trying to pull the data, config file from the F drive.

Is there anyway to update the paths to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

> Stop the server a source
>   Change the config file parameters such as datadir,basedir,log-directory etc(All variables which are path specific)
>   You may need to change log-bin.index file as well in logs directory
>   Move the directory to new path
>   Start the server
>   verify the services

Hope it helps and share any error message if you face any.